# How to use objectId validation in joiful?

Tags: node.js, validation, joi

I tried to joiful validation using mongodb objectId.but its throwing error **Property 'ObjectId' does not exist on type 'typeof import("/home/lenovo/Music/basic/node_modules/joiful/index")'**

```
import * as jf from "joiful";
import {ObjectId} from 'mongodb';
class SignUp {
    @jf.string().required()
    username?: string;

    @jf
        .string()
        .required()
        .min(8)
    password?: string;

    @jf.date()
    dateOfBirth?: Date;

    @jf.boolean().required()
    subscribedToNewsletter?: boolean;

    @jf.ObjectId().required()
    id?:ObjectId;
}

const signUp = new SignUp();
signUp.username = "rick.sanchez";
signUp.password = "wubbalubbadubdub";

const { error } = jf.validate(signUp);
```

Is it possible to validate objectId using joiful.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this question is along time ago, and the library maintainers didn't add this validator yet, for that I created a custom decorator that uses `joiful` custom method to make custom validation

```js
import * as jf from 'joiful';
import Joi from 'joi';
import { ObjectId } from 'mongodb';

export const objectIdValidationDecorator = () => jf.any().custom(({ schema }: { schema: Joi.Schema }) => {
  return schema.custom((value, helpers) => {
    const objectId = new ObjectId(value);
    if (objectId.equals(value)) {
      return objectId;
    } else {
      return helpers.error('any.invalid');
    }
  });
})
```

Usage:

```js
class MyObj {
  @objectIdValidationDecorator().required()
  referenceId:ObjectId
}
```